# Non-sequential alt tags rendered inside Fancybox with nested YAML list (Jekyll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jekyll, fancybox-3

I'm trying to figure out why the alt tags being dynamically inserted into Fancybox 3’s rendered img tag are coming up in seemingly random order.

I've got a YAML list in Jekyll, and the alt tags are stored after the images:

```
- project:
  -
    name: Jupiter
    thumb_url: jupiter-thumb.png
    thumb_alt: Jupiter!
    main:
      - image: jupiter_pic_1, alt1
      - image: jupiter_pic_2, alt2
      - image: jupiter_pic_3, alt3
      - image: jupiter_pic_4, alt4
```

I have a loop that uses Fancybox:

```
        {% for main in project.main %}

          {% assign main = site.data.project[0].main[0] %}
          {% assign data = main.image|split:"," %}

            <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox="{{ project.name }}" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ site.image_path }}/{{ data[2] | strip }}/{{ data[0] }}.png"
            data-caption="{{ site.blurb }}" data-alt="{{ data[1] }}">

            <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ site.image_path }}/{{ project.thumb_url }}" alt="{{ project.thumb_alt }}" /></a>

        {% endfor %}
```

So the loop loops through the YAML list and grabs the relevant information (project name, URLs, alt tags) and inserts it into the Fancybox markup.

I've got this jQuery, to add an alt tag to the rendered Fancybox image markup. **I think that the issue has something to do with the loading interval of this**:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function (instance, slide) {
       $(".fancybox-image").attr("alt", slide.opts.$orig.data('alt'));
    }
  });
```

`{{ data[1] }}` holds the alt tags from project > main.

When I load the page and inspect it, I see this:

`<img class="fancybox-image" src=“/path/to/jupiter_pic_1.png" alt=" alt4">`

But it should be:

`<img class="fancybox-image" src="/path/to/jupiter_pic_1.png" alt=" alt1">`

And when I scroll to the next image, it should be:

`<img class="fancybox-image" src="/path/to/jupiter_pic_2.png" alt=" alt2">`

In the page source, though, the markup is exactly the way it should be:

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox="Jupiter" href="/path/to/jupiter_pic_1.png"
            data-caption="A caption" data-alt=" alt1”>

            <img class="img-responsive" src="/path/to/jupiter-thumb.png" alt="Jupiter!" /></a>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I think I got it: `onComplete: function (instance, slide) {` - in case this helps anyone out!

Comment: *... the markup is exactly the way it should be* - It's not clear how correct it is. Do the `<a><img/></a>` fragments line up in the expected order, or not?

Comment: The page source is structurally correct, and has the correct content (`pic_1` and `alt1`). But Fancybox's *rendered* HTML at the top of the page was not correct. It was showing random alt tags, out of order. `onComplete` fixed that.

Comment: bunnycode, maybe you could find time to post a full answer. Stack Overflow allows you to accept own answers.

Comment: This question is duplicate of your previous question where you accepted the incorrect answer.